# breaking apart a math expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a text-box in which the input is a simple math expression like `2+323*4.5/5` or `2 +  323*4.5 /5` (I mean the white spaces should be ignored). **Both integers and floats** are possible and acceptable as input. I want to break apart every element of this expression (**both operands and operators**) and save them into an array, so that I can send the first operand, the first operator, and the second operand (as parameters of an atomic calculation) to a PHP page (server) and then after getting the server's response, send the second operator and the third operand together with the server's previous response in order to perform another atomic operation and so on.

For example, if the initial string is `2 +  323*4.5 /5`, my array (the result) should look like this:

[2, +, 323, *, 4.5, /, 5].

I used the match method as follows:

```
var expr = document.getElementById("txtExpr").value; 
var tokens = expr.match(/-*\/?[0-9]/g);
```

But I can't use "+" sign and the result array is not what I'm looking for. It concatenates the operator to the next operand.

**PS: I NEED TO ACCEPT/GET NEGATIVE NUMERS AS WELL.**

Comment: FWIW, JavaScript can also perform all mathematical calculations. Possibly there is no need in sending all the data to the backend.

Comment: You should be more specific on what classifies as a "simple expression". Negative numbers? Only +/-/*/:? What about '.5' instead of '0.5'? My advice would be looking for an open-source expression parser (there are some, I used them before – but I forgot the names) rather than writing your own. Except it's crystal clear what expressions you want to support and whether they are "simple" enough.

Comment: http://pegjs.majda.cz/ <-- Way more powerful than regExp for this kind of task.

Comment: @IngoBürk This is a course assignment, so I should implement it by myself.

Comment: @VisioN This assignment is about distributed systems. In the next step, they're going to teach us that we can (and we should) move the calculations part to the client side as well to reduce the server load. So, that's the next step. However, thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"2 + 323*4.5 / 5".match(/\d*\.\d+|\d+|[/*+-]/g);
// >> ["2", "+", "323", "*", "4.5", "/", "5"]
```

Comment: What if I want to accept the negative numbers as well, as an element (not a "-" operator as an element and the number after that as another separate element)?